# Ruby on rails validation bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, data-modeling

For some when registering the validate_uniqueness_of is not working even though it works when running the console

```
2.1.5 :001 > User.create_with_password('rajiv', 'abc')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" = 'rajiv' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, username: "rajiv", salt: "ddda20c52e698f6e5623d7e782e2cd19", password_hash: "565b91a38e2acc41887e3936fe660b68245b3f1d8118f38bbc..."> 
2.1.5 :002 > 

def register
    @username = params[:Username]
    @password = params[:password]
    @rePassword = params[:rePassword]
    user = User.create_with_password(@username, @password)
      if user
        session[:signed_in] = true
        session[:username] = user.username
        flash[:notice] = "User successfully created you can sign in now"
        redirect_to '/Sign_up'
      else
        flash[:notice] = "User already exists"
end
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong the website im running it on is:

https://ipt-dynaman.c9.io/Sign_up

here is my model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :username, :salt, :password_hash
   validates_uniqueness_of :username

    def self.create_with_password(username, password)
        salt = SecureRandom.hex
        password_hash = self.generate_hash(password, salt)

        self.create(
        username: username,
        salt: salt,
        password_hash: password_hash
        )
    end

    def verify_password(password)
       self.password_hash == User.generate_hash(password, self.salt) 
    end

    def self.generate_hash(password, salt)
        digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
        digest.update(password)
        digest.update(salt)
        digest.to_s
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

Have your controller create an instance, set the attributes, and save.  Your validations will work.  See the [ActionController Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) in the
Rails guides.

Comment: Thanks :D ill check out devise

Comment: create isn't just for relations. Also save and save! both run validations - they just differ in what they do if the validations say the record is invalid.

Comment: True about `save` and `save!` The second throws an exception when validations fail.  I don't find any `create` method for ActiveRecord other than for associations.  The answer references the 'rails way'.

Comment: Okay,  save vs. save! vs. create weren't relevant to the gist of the answer anyway; so, I've boiled it down.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that authentication systems and cryptography are tricky to get right, your mistake is simple.

When choosing whether to redirect to a success page or render an error message, you are testing the truthiness of `user`. However as your console tests show, your `create_with_password` returns a non nil user if the validation fails. That user is not valid and is not saved in the database, but this is not what your controller is testing for.

Instead of checking for whether `user` is truthy, you could instead check `user.valid?`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Save!` to make sure if validations fail. The transactions will rollback